# Custom template error after update magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, template, upgrade

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Mage_Core_Block_Template::setTemplate()  in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 111

0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(111): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Missing argumen...', '/var/www/magent...', 111, Array)
1 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Block_Template->setTemplate()
2 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
3 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
4 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
9 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
10 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
11 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
12 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
13 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
14 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
15 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
16 /var/www/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
17 {main}
```

I got this error after updated my magento. I have no idea why its happened. Need some help here.

Answer (score 0):

When setting a template, you'll need to set the relative template path in the setTemplate() method. This error tells you that you didn't set a value there, so just set the correct template path and you're good.

Comment: How do we do that?

Comment: That depends, you can either set it with PHP with `$variable->setTemplate('path/to/my/template.phtml');` or with XML with `<block type="module/block" name="my.block" template="path/to/my/template" />`. You'll need to find out which file currently breaks and fix that file. Which file that is, is hard to tell from the code you've added.